# How do I manipulate a field grid in Illustrator to resemble spacetime so that the center of the grid dips below a sphere?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, grids

Think of a bowling ball that has rolled to the center of a trampoline. I would like to depict that in Illustrator, except the trampoline would be a grid that conforms to the weight of the bowling ball (the planet in the example below).

[image: original image from http://www.space.com/images/i/000/046/071/original/pulsar-J1906-disappears.jpg]

Comment: Can you use parametric surfaces of multivariate functions to make grids?

Comment: To my knowledge, these are not available in illustrator.

Comment: Darn. That would be a very clever solution assuming one could get their hands on a closed form version of the relativistic curvature formulae.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found an interesting option [in this video](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-combine-envelope-distort-with-grids--vector-4784).

Start by creating a grid with the **Rectangular Grid** or **Polar Grid** tool.

Click **Object** > **Envelope Distort** > **Make with Mesh**

Add some perspective with the **Effect** > **3D** > **Rotate** and adjust to your liking.

Move the points from the Mesh grid (not your original grid) until you get the desired effect.
Go back and tweak the settings in the Rectangular grid and Envelope Distort tools if the result is still not good enough.

This is my final result after just a few minutes doing what I just described:

[image: Grid mesh warp]